# FB.ui not returning post_id anymore

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The post is actually getting shared correctly via the `FB.ui` share dialog, but the "response" from facebook is an empty array `[]`.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://example.com/',
    picture: 'http://example.com/image.jpg',
    name: 'name',
    description: 'test description',
    caption: 'site.com'
}, function(response) {
    console.log( response )
});
```

It worked fine until few hours ago... is there something wrong in their `API`, do you have any knowledge of that ?

Thanks !

Comment: see my answer, i can add additional information if you tell me exactly why you would want to get the post id.

Comment: I'm tracking how many sales we got from people sharing ( as I'm adding an affiliateID to the link that gets shared so we can see if there's any actual improvement coming from there.

Comment: ok, that does sound like it would be allowed, but it´s still not possible. and you really don´t want to make users authorize your app with publish_actions just for that - also, you would not get it approved by facebook for statistical things.

Comment: Hm... boss would really be pissed off now as I have just spent one month on changing 4 sales websites to work with the affiliate tracking system. Any advice on what I could do ?

Comment: there´s nothing you can do, unfortunately. for statistical stuff, you have to use the facebook insights. you can only check if users open the feed dialog (right before calling FB.ui), but that does not always mean they really shared it.

Comment: Well then it's my fault for not reading that more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only get a proper response and a Post ID if you authorize the user with the `publish_actions` permission. This is most likely to prevent developers from doing something that is not allowed - rewarding users in some way for sharing or gating content.

Comment: This is true, but you will run into different problem here. Facebook will not grant ```publish_actions``` if you using this share dialog, so there is no way how to get this permissions here (unless you are using custom share dialog :D ). Trust me I try. Facebook have actually big mess with this.

Comment: it is not a big mess, it is to prevent people from doing something that is not allowed, as you can read in my answer ;)

Comment: Well from my point of view it is.

1) I read documentation and learn from it that if I want to know if user shared or cancel using standard share dialog I need publish_actions.

2) ok than I will ask for this permission.

3) I will never get this permissions because I'm using this dialog.

4) I will make my own dialog for getting this permissions.

So the answer for question is: You will never know if user shared because there is no way to get publish_actions with share dialog.

Comment: you will get the permission, but not for doing something that is not allowed. that´s the important part. now if you are using publish_actions for something else too, and need to know the post id (NOT for incentivizing)....you get the point? ;)

Comment: either way, people who ask that question usually want to do something that is not allowed anyway. not in this case, but in almost all other ones i´ve seen on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the *user* has to have granted `publish_actions` to our app.  Facebook's documentation simply says that ["post_id requires your app to have publish_actions granted"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/).  In other words, the user doing the publishing has to have granted `publish_actions`; simply having `publish_actions` granted on the app from which the post is made is insufficient.